# bash $PS1 containing an emoj

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, command-line

This question is related to 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/357132/44531

I would like to have a space after the emoj . I've tried in the script below but I'm getting two lines instead of the hoped for single line. And, No I do not want two spaces appear in the zero return code case as I coded up in my original answer.

[image]

```
mac RC=1 $ declare -f highlightExitCode
highlightExitCode () 
{ 
    exit_code=$?;
    if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
        echo -en " RC=${exit_code} "'\xf0\x9f\x98\xb1\x0a\x00';
    else
        echo -e "";
    fi
}
mac $ echo $PS1
\u$(highlightExitCode) \$
mac $ 
mac $ er
-bash: er: command not found
mac RC=127 $ 
# FYI: I edited out the non-appearing space 
#in my terminal output
```

I'm running macOS 10.10.5.

```
 mac RC=127 
  $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
mac $
```

When I try to add a space in the code below, I get a new line added.

[image]

```
mac $ echo $PS1
\u$(highlightExitCode) \$
mac $ declare -f highlightExitCode
highlightExitCode () 
{ 
    exit_code=$?;
    if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
        echo -en " RC=${exit_code} "'\xf0\x9f\x98\xb1\x0a\x00'" ";
    else
        echo -e "";
    fi
}
mac $ error
-bash: error: command not found
mac RC=127 
  $ 
mac RC=127 
  $ 
mac RC=127 
  $
```

-------- fyi ------------

actually, when I copy and past here I get a space after the emoj, but the space doesn't appear in my mac terminal.

```
mac RC=127  $ 
mac $ 
mac $ 
mac $
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Using your first example (with the space in the definition of PS1) I get a space between the emoji and the `$`. Bash version is `3.2.57(1)-release`.

Comment: FWIW `printf '\xf0\x9f\x98\xb1\x20\x0a'` returns ' ' without the quotes and the prompt in on the next line and there is a space after .

Comment: Are you aware that you can put the emoji in there directly, as it's unicode? I had the coffee cup emoji in my $PS1 for ages, worked fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always wrap in additional command substitutions to do this, for eg:

```
$ printf "%s  <-- some space after it" "$(echo -en " RC=${exit_code} "'\xf0\x9f\x98\xb1\x0a')"
 RC=   <-- some space after it
```

I'm not sure why you have that NUL character (`\x00`) trailing but with that I was getting this error message:

```
$ printf "%s  <-- some space after it" "$(echo -en " RC=${exit_code} "'\xf0\x9f\x98\xb1\x0a\x00')"
-bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
 RC=   <-- some space after it
```

So I simply removed it.

Here I've wrapped your original `echo` command in a command substitution `$(..command..)` and then passed its output to `printf` to produce any additional formatting.

General structure:

```
$ printf "%s ...." "$(..command to produce output..)"
```

#### Additional Example

You could also use `printf` exclusively. I'm not entirely sure what your goal is here but you could do something like this:

```
$ printf "RC=${exit_code} \xf0\x9f\x98\xb1  <-- some space after it\n\n"
RC=   <-- some space after it
```

The UTF-8 code `\x0a` is a linefeed character, the above example removed it + the NUL, `\x00` and added 2 newlines to the end instead, `\n\n`.

Comment: You made a key observation about the extra \x00 and \x0a.  I had forgotten about the difference between echo and echo -n.

Comment: My problem was I copied from Maghin whose version of hexdump defaulted to having the -x option and Maghin used just echo.  The combination of the two result in \x00 and \x0a being included.  I've never seen emojs in hex before.  I didn't know what I was looking at so I was doing blind copies.  I recommend using hexdump -C to get a better display.

Comment: @historystamp - i deal w/ UTF-8 and hex all the time so it jumped right out at me 8-). Is your issue resolved then?

Comment: Yes.  Once I got rid of \x00 and \x0a things worked as expected. I do have a question. How does echo know the character is one or two bytes long?

Comment: @historystamp that's how UTF-8 works. It's variable width, the first 2 bits specify that it's UTF of the 1st byte, the next 2 bits of the 2nd byte can either be a continuation marker or not.  This video oversimplifies it but illustrates it well enough - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4.

Comment: @historystamp - wikipedia page has table that shows it for UTF-8 in the 1 byte vs. 4 byte config - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. The characters encoded into the scheme are called code points - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point.